# htaccess rewrite rule with multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [S=20]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ index.php?occ=$1&cat=$2
```

now these 2 lines together are not working for example:

if I were to go to contact.php, I would type in my url: localhost/website/contact
and it would work

however if I want to go to location/website/index.php?occ=occasion&cat=category by typing this in my url: localhost/website/occasion/category it will only work if I remove the first rewrite rule

but then I cant go to localhost/website/contact anymore

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Problem is your order.

`/website/occasion/category` first gets rewritten to be `/website/occasion/category.php`, which then fails to match the second rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ index.php?occ=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Changing the order and adding the `[L]` parameter to the rule (stop executing followup rules after succesful execution) should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^site_1/(.*)$ site_1/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^site_2/(.*)$ site_2/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

as in sites you won't have 1000s of sites you can declare your desire link and folder name
e.g.
if your structure is

```
/home/site1, /home/site2
```

and links will be like http://yourdomain.com/medical & http://yourdomain.com/entertainment